# Disk Utility doesn't give option to format thumb drive as Encrypted

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan

I am trying to format thumb drive as `Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted)`. However, this option is not available. Is this some restriction for thumb drive?

Comment: What kind of partition table does your drive have on it right now: MBR or GPT? If MBR, see if switching it to GPT gives you more options in Disk Utility.

Comment: Yes, now it gives Encryption choice.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and this answer on [Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/encrypt-external-usb-thumb-drive-on-macos-high-sierra?newreg=18f28fb51ac2490cadc7509c551c2a14) worked for me.

---

*Including the full answer posted by [Mortiz Petersen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/64318/moritz-petersen) from the above link here.*

This is an example workflow to encrypt an USB thumbdrive with HSF+ (Journaled) with `diskutil` using the command line.

Assuming you start with a MS-DOS formatted USB stick.

Step 1: List all currently mounted disks `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.1 GB     disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 MYSTORAGE               8.1 GB     disk2s1
```

You see the disk `MYSTORAGE` has the identifier `disk2s1` and is `DOS_FAT_32` formatted.

Step 2: Now format the disk `disk2` as HSF+ (Journaled):

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ "New Storage" GPT disk2
```

The name of the disk will be "New Storage". At this time it is not yet encrypted. Look at the list of disks `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.1 GB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS New Storage             7.7 GB     disk2s2
```

Step 3: Now you see the "New Storage" partition with identifier `disk2s2`. Encrypt this partition using:

```
diskutil cs convert disk2s2 -passphrase
```

Enter the passphrase when prompted.

If you list the disks now, you also see the encrypted logical volume `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *8.1 GB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage New Storage             7.7 GB     disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk2s3

/dev/disk3 (external, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS New Storage            +7.3 GB     disk3
                                 Logical Volume on disk2s2
                                 8B474F90-34B7-49FE-95E0-E8B260C51CCF
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

---

If you skip step 3, you can also encrypt the disk using Finder:

[image: Right-click on the drive and select "Encrypt drive-name"]

Just right-click on the drive and select "Encrypt drive-name".

> **Caution:** If you choose this alternative approach, the disk gets formatted as APFS encrypted disk!

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you [edit your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1312689/edit) and include the information from that ASE answer here? Thanks :)

Comment: Updated, let me know if that's the correct way to go about it :)